# How jquery project do code coverage test

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-coverage

I know jQuery use [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) for unit test,
but what tool for javascript code-coverage test? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer possibly:

jscoverage

http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/instrumented-jquery/jscoverage.html?test/index.html